# Aligning a gallery on the center of the page

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin, text-align

I have a portfolio website and I'm trying to align the pictures in the center of the page. I've tried

```
text-align
```

and

```
margin
```

but nothing seems to work. The code and CSS are as follows:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class=responsive>
        <div class=image>
            <img class="gallery" src="../pics/placeholder.png">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
.body {
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 20px;
   float: left;
}

.responsive {
   padding: 5px;
   float: left
}

.gallery {
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: what is the style for <div class="image">?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `.responsive` and add `width:100%` to `.body`

Then you don't need `float` on `.body` also.

But it all depends how you want to design your page.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the `float: left` without the set `width` is messing up your ability to center things.

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.body {
   padding-top: 20px;
   float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive {
   padding: 5px;
   float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
}
.gallery {
   width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="responsive">
        <div class="image">
            <img class="gallery" src="https://img1.wsimg.com/fos/sales/cwh/8/images/cats-with-hats-shop-02.jpg">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```